# Card flip inside Bootstrap modal with dynamicly imported image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm making a sort of card game. I'm using Bootstrap 3 as my framework with a deck of cards in a grid, each card in their own column.

When a card is clicked, I want the card to be displayed with its backside up as an overlay, like Bootstraps modal or equivalent. But when the card is clicked (or touched) it should flip, displaying the front which is the same as the image that was clicked to trigger the modal. It should be able to flip back and forward infinite number of times. Clicking outside the modal or on a close button, closes the modal and returns to the deck.

I'm able to do a card flip on an image. And I'm able to trigger a modal with dynamic content. But what I can't figure out is how to do this together so that I don't have to create a seperate modal for each card.

I've been pulling my hair over this issue for days now and I truly cannot wrap my head around how this can be made. My javascript skills are quite limited and I cant find any plugin or code example to help me in this (I've tried numerous options).

My grid is displayed in the snippet. No data-targets, modules or javascripts included though since I havn't found anything that works yet.

Any ideas?

```css
main {
  .container-fluid;
  .text-center;
  background: none;
  header {
    .container-fluid;
    .text-center;
    padding: 50px;
    h1 {
      font-weight: @font-weight-heading;
    }
  }
  .cardColumns {
    .make-row();
    .cCard {
      .make-xs-column(4);
      .make-sm-column(3);
      .make-md-column(2);
      padding: 10px;
      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        .img-rounded;
        modal-body-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #000;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }
      img:hover {
        modal-body-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 #000;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="cardColumns">
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cCard">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/card.jpg" alt="Perspiciatis">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: If each one of your cards is a div with image of the card, It has two mode close and open: `.card.closed{ transform: rotateY(180deg);}` you can toogle the `.closed` class to open/close the card. and you must add this to hide the content when it is closed: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

This basically just changes the background image in the mid spin.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initListeners();
});

function initListeners() {
  $(".container").off();
  $(".container").on("click",function() {
    $(".container").removeClass("toggle")
    $(this).addClass("toggle");
  });
}

/*var Cards;
setTimeout(function() {
  Cards = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
  for (let i = 0; i < (e = Cards.length); i++)
    Cards[i].addEventListener("click", function(elem) {
      for (let i = 0; i < (e = Cards.length); i++)
        Cards[i].classList.remove('toggle');
      elem.target.parentElement.classList.add('toggle');
    });
}, 1);*/
```

```css
.container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  transition: transform .35s linear;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcRWf.png) center center;
  background-size: cover!important;
  transition: background 0.01s linear;
  transition-delay: 0.175s;
}

.container.toggle .card {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.container.toggle .card::after {
  background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f4/e3/97/f4e397ef5e0a4cd7cdbf30e65aa149c0.jpg) center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting it...  :( I want the deck to be face up. When the user clicks or touches a card. The card is either opened up in a modal overlay(prefered solution), or a new page(but then a dynamic page since I can't  have a seperate page for each card). I'ts not important if in the overlay it starts face up or down as long as it can be flipped back and forth.

So the modal shows the chosen card, which can be turned over and back again. The faces are different, the background is the same for every card. (It's a planning poker game that is responsive if that makes it more clear) :)

Comment: http://svanlund.nu/CHASlocal/ on this link is an incredibly rough version of what I want to achieve. The issue here is that it's not a back side of the card that it flips to. But this was the closest I could get. .

Answer (score 0):

Copy pest code in individual file and check in your local it will run. perfect. Given below is modern way of doing it. You can refer [this link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) for further details of the way of creating modal dynamically.

With that also i have used external js to flip images reference to which you will get [here](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/).

```js
$('.flip-card').flip();


function openModal(front_image, back_image) {
  var message = $('#modal_1');
  BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: $('#modal_1'),
    onshown: function() {
      $('.front img').attr('src', front_image);
      $('.back img').attr('src', back_image);
    },
    onhide: function(dialogRef) {
      $('#hidden-div').append(message);
    },
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="openModal('http://fillmurray.com/200/200','http://fillmurray.com/600/600')">Open modal</button>


<div id="hidden-div" style="display: none">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="modal_1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="flip-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');" style="height : 300px;">
          <div class="front front-side" style="">
            <img src="" alt="" style="width : 100%; height: 100%">
          </div>
          <div class="back back-side" style="background-color : blue">
            <img src="" alt="" style="width : 100%; height: 100%">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```